# Can I use servlet api 3.0 and jetty 8?

Tags: servlets, servlet-3.0, jetty-8

I want to use 3.0 servlet-api with Jetty 8. Currently 2.4 servlet-api is defined in my web.xml. And in the webdefault.xml 2.5 servlet-api is defined. Someone else set this up so they very well might have done something wrong. Which servlet-api version am I actually using? 2.4 or 2.5? I have 3.0 already in my classpath. What do I need to change in web.xml and/or webdefault.xml to get it working?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11):

You normally don't provide the Servlet API yourself. This is normally to be provided by the target servletcontainer itself. Examples of Servlet 3.0 compatible containers are [Tomcat 7.x](http://tomcat.apache.org), [Glassfish 3.x](http://glassfish.java.net), [JBoss AS 6.x/7.x](http://jboss.org/jbossas) and, yes, [Jetty 8.x](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/).

You just have to declare the `<web-app>` root element of `web.xml` to comply the highest version as supported by the target container.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

</web-app>
```

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: _minor note_: sometimes it helps to set `metadata-complete="false"`. (I had to in Jboss 7 for the first time.)